# WPF element hosted in ElementHost not redrawing correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, elementhost, hwndsource

I'm writing a program to implement COM component in C#. This component provides a UI component too. In the interest of making it easy to implement future additions to the component, I decided to write the UI in Xaml using WPF and wrapping it in an ElementHost control to provide the handle back to to the COM consumer.

Here's where this gets interesting. The element is being hosted in a win32 tab control. The first time the tab is selected, it loads fine. Switching to another tab and coming back causes it to not draw the component correctly. If I move the mouse through it, it'll draw the TextBox elements, but it'll never redraw the whole UserComponent.

I've tried every possible solution I've seen suggested, from changing the height/width values of the component to putting the HwndTarget in SoftwareOnly rendering mode.

I'm not sure what to try at this point, so suggestions are welcome. I'd really like to do this without using Windows Forms as the future maintainers of this aren't the best programmers and it's a lot easier to tell them to write up a Xaml file with data bindings than manually lay out a form and set the values in the code-behind.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, please write here solution if you found it. Probably this will help you: [ElementHost source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Integration/System/Windows/Integration/ElementHost@cs/4/ElementHost@cs)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't met such problem yet.
Try to force refresh or focus (methods) to the hosting wrapper or HwndSource when switching to the hosting tab.